# Commutator of parity and Hamiltonian operators under even potential function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

I need to show what is $[H,P]$ where $H$ is the Hamiltonian and $P$ the parity operator. $V(\underset{\sim}x) = V(-\underset{\sim}x)$ in this case.

I start off with

$$ 
\langle \underset{\sim}x|HP|\psi\rangle
= \langle \underset{\sim}x|(\frac{p^2}{2m}+V)P|\psi\rangle
= \langle \underset{\sim}x|(\frac{p^2}{2m}+V)P|\psi\rangle
= \langle \underset{\sim}x|\frac{p^2}{2m}P|\psi\rangle+\langle \underset{\sim}x|VP|\psi\rangle
$$

and since $\langle \underset{\sim}x|V = V(\underset{\sim}x)\langle \underset{\sim}x|$ (is this step valid?) and $ \langle \underset{\sim}x|P = \langle -\underset{\sim}x|$, the above equation becomes

$$
\langle \underset{\sim}x|HP|\psi\rangle
= \langle \underset{\sim}x|\frac{p^2}{2m}P|\psi\rangle + V(\underset{\sim}x)\psi(-\underset{\sim}x)
$$

Similarly I have

$$
\langle \underset{\sim}x|PH|\psi\rangle
= \langle \underset{\sim}x|P\frac{p^2}{2m}|\psi\rangle + V(-\underset{\sim}x)\psi(-\underset{\sim}x)
= \langle \underset{\sim}x|P\frac{p^2}{2m}|\psi\rangle + V(\underset{\sim}x)\psi(-\underset{\sim}x)
$$

Taking the difference of the two, I find that

$$
\langle \underset{\sim}x|HP-PH|\psi\rangle
= \langle \underset{\sim}x|\frac{p^2}{2m}P-P\frac{p^2}{2m}|\psi\rangle
= -\langle \underset{\sim} x|\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i^2}P|\psi \rangle +\langle -\underset{\sim} x|\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i^2}|\psi\rangle
$$

which I had trouble evaluating. Any hints?

Comment: I don't see how you can't just plug in the definitions. How are things defined? Also have you learned about the wavevector basis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is an easier way to go about this. Acting with the Parity operator on the Hamiltonian we have:
\begin{align} 
P \hat{H} P & = \hat{H} ( - x ) \\ 
\Rightarrow  P \hat{H} & = \hat{H} ( - x ) P
\end{align} 
So the Hamiltonian commutes with the Parity operator if $ \hat{H} ( x ) = \hat{H} ( - x ) $. Now 
\begin{equation} 
\frac{ p ^2 }{ 2 m } = -  \frac{1}{ 2m} \frac{ \partial ^2 }{ \partial x ^2 } \xrightarrow{P}  -  \frac{1}{ 2m} \frac{ \partial ^2 }{ \partial (-x) ^2 } =-  \frac{1}{ 2m} \frac{ \partial ^2 }{ \partial x ^2 }
\end{equation} 
So the momenta squared in invariant. Furthermore, if 
\begin{equation} 
V ( - x ) = V ( x ) 
\end{equation} 
then the potential is also invariant. Thus we have,
\begin{equation} 
\hat{H} ( - x ) = \hat{H} ( x ) 
\end{equation}
 and the Hamiltonian must commute with the parity operator.

Comment: Saying "it's trivially invariant" when it is exactly the problem of the OP is not answering the question...

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what the complaint was. But I updated the answer to make it more clear.